How can I insert a box between 2 rows? I don't want that box starts at the beginning of a row, I want that start and finish in the middle of a row
Obviously is something more complicated but i'd like a clear and simple description

I tried with grid and flexbox layout, setted "align-self: center" to the right box, but nothing happens, asked to ChatGPT and Perplexity too but I'm stuck.
I just want to display the third box (in a possible flex or grid layout of 3 box) in the right, centered in the middle of first and second left box.
This is the example code:


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  flex: 1 1 calc(60% - 1.5rem);
  height: 250px;
}

.box3 {
  flex: 1 1 calc(40% - 1.5rem);
  height: 250px;
  align-self: center;
}
<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1"></div>
   <div class="box box2"></div>
   <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>




CSS-Grid with five rows would be ideal. Each box spans two rows.


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  grid-row: 1 /span 2;
}

.box2 {
  grid-row: 3 /span 2;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 100px;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>




The simplest solution you're looking for using flex could be as follows.
Have defined the height of the container and made flex changes to get the desired layout.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  height: 600px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 50%;
}

.box3 {
  align-self: center;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
</div>



Hope, this helps.

My suggestion would be adding bootstrap to your file.
It would be more easy. Or else you can use the same classes in your css. But make sure you follow the same order for div's  in order to use the same code structure.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <style>
      .box {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        height: 250px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="col-6 p-2 d-grid">
            <div class="box my-2 box1"></div>
            <div class="box my-2 box2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 p-2 d-grid">
            <div class="box my-2 align-self-center box3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




Maybe you can do it with CSS grid, and adjust the max-width or the columns:


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  align-self: center;
}
<div class="container">
   <div class="box box1"></div>
   <div class="box box2"></div>
   <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>



in grid-template-columns, you can adjust the number for less or more size in the boxes, or you can do it with max-width too. I use grid-column-start and grid-column-end for better understanding of whats happening.

While the code actually works for the given requirement, it fixes the height of the third box. So if we had the requirement to let the third box grow in case we add more content to it as compared to the first or second box, that text would overflow.

I hope that might help, it's my first time commenting in here. I think it was more practical to add the two layouts in the HTML, and I erased the box1, box2, box3 class since everything is applied to the layout:

the first layout is a column with everything centered and two elements.
in the second one there's only one centered element.

You can just give diferent widths or flex to the layout1 and 2 or to the boxes inside if you wanna see a different size :)
Hope that helps!
ps. in your case, trying to align with align-self won't work since there's only one row, and you can't make it go through those limits without using margins, which is definitely not recommended.


.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.layout1,.layout2{
  display:flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.box {
width:100%;
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
<div class="container">
   <div class="layout1">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
      <div class="layout2">
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
</div>



